# Are links inside checkbox labels acceptable?

Tags: accessibility, checkboxes

For checkboxes in forms, you often need an accompanying link for individual options. This regularly comes up in checkboxes to accept terms of use. Designers love to put this link *inside* the checkbox label like this:

[image: A checkbox form element with the text Please agree to the terms of use, where the terms of use are underlined to indicate a link]

I disagree with this, as clicking on the label should toggle the checkbox. Having the link inside the label reduces the click target size, and creates two click targets right next to each other.

I prefer a separate link below the checkbox label:

[image: The same checkbox, but with the link to the terms of use as a separate link below the label]

Am I correct that this is better for usability and accessibility? If so, is there an authoritative source for this?

[This related question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/108987/are-checkbox-options-with-hyperlink-a-good-practice) only talks about the entire label being a link, which is obviously bad. My colleague argues that it's OK if only part of the label is a link, since there's still a large enough click target for the label itself. [Technique H44](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html) only talks about clickable labels, but doesn't mention anything about links inside those labels.

Comment: Are you primarily concerned about accessibility (with assistive technology) or general usability? I would prefer the first approach for its conciseness and clarity.

Comment: If separated, I would recommend to place the instruction ("*Please read the terms of use*") first, above the checkbox that lets me confirm "*I agree to the terms of use*". Also I'd still put the link only on the words "terms of use", not on the entire sentence.

Comment: An answer already mentioned the issue with this with screen readers, so I won’t create a new one talking about that, but I feel compelled to point out that this is a great excuse to learn the basics of using a screen reader (and possibly keyboard-only navigation). It’s a remarkably useful skill to have as a UI designer because it lets you test how people who need one will _actually_ interact with your website/app, which makes it much easier to make a site/app that’s properly accessible.

Comment: Your proposed "improvement" made the linked text a smaller font.  That's a problem all on its own.

Comment: This is a "feature" of the Close Vote dialog on many SE sites.  I've stopped counting how many times I've accidentally followed a link when trying to select one of the options (using a mouse).

Comment: @Bergi Both! I think putting the link first makes sense for options where the majority of people will require an explanation. For terms of use specifically, 99% of people won't want to click on the link, so having it after the checkbox and slightly deemphasized makes sense. Why only have the link on terms of use? This just reduces the click target size.

Comment: @BenVoigt That's just a quick screenshot from Figma, it's not 'to scale'. Of course the assumption in both versions is that the text has the recommended minimum font size. The text being slightly smaller to de-emphasize it is not inherently a problem IMO, only if it is so small as to be illegible, or has poor contrast.

Comment: Off-topic nitpick: "Please agree to the terms of use" is a request, whereas checkboxes are basically "yes/no" answers. "Checking" a request seems cognitively dissonant to me. Text should at least be as in the second example, ie "I agree...".

Comment: The second one looks like it also "reduces the click target size, and creates two click targets right next to each other", in perhaps a worse way because the vertical size of the click target is more limiting than the horizontal size. Separating the two pieces of text and/or making them the same font size would help with this.

Comment: @PabloH You're right! Was already corrected by the time I took the second screenshot :)

Comment: @bjb568 Good point! I'll make sure to add some spacing between the two.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Screen readers will read the first example something like this:

> Please agree to the [pause]
> link, terms of use.

As you can imagine, the broken up sentence can be confusing.

So the second example is preferred. To make the relation between the label and the link clear for screen reader users, you can add the `aria-describedby` attribute to the label that points to the link.
<sub>[See here for more info about aria-describedby.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-describedby)</sub>

Comment: Thanks! Demonstrating how screenreaders will read the sentence is a good argument! In combination with the click-target issue, this should be convincing enough :)

Comment: It is extremely common to have hyperlinked words in the middle of sentences. (I see four such links on this very webpage!) Why would it be any more confusing in this particular case? Or are you saying the practice should be avoided in general?

Comment: @Carmeister It’s partly about user expectations. It’s unusual to have mixed controls (links _are_ controls from a UX perspective) nested within other controls, so users will generally not expect this. However, it’s also about effective navigation. Consider how this structure interacts with tab indexing.

Comment: Accessible UI is going to have the text toggle the checkbox on or off when clicked or tapped, e.g using:
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value">
<label for="checkbox_id">Text</label>
So clicking on a link inside a label would create a conflict.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn This isn't really "nested within other controls", the two controls are separate. Most sites don't use a nested presentation as in the OP.

Comment: @Barmar Having the link in the label would be a nested control, because the label is part of the checkbox control as almost every web browser and UI toolkit implements checkboxes.

Comment: Right the expectation is for labels to be part of the control they are adhered to (via id).  e.g. `<label for="some-control-id">some label</label>` has particular behavior when clicked depending on the control.  To nest a link in there would be awkward.

Answer (score 6):

For touchscreen users, the click targets are better separated for link inside the label:

[image: Drawing of user finger clicking on labels]

The practice of putting a link inside label seems widespread enough that in my opinion it won't confuse users. That may depend on audience.

In any case, don't place two click targets that close vertically, it is very difficult to click accurately on one of them.

Comment: Would it be an improvement if the link is aligned to the right? This would create more distance and satisfy @jazZRo's answer.